# Horizontal scrollbar on bootstrap 3.3.7 website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, css-selectors

It has a horizontal scroll despite me using rows and columns to fill it up.

[Here](https://github.com/vuskovic09/The-Solar-System-PraktikumWD) is the GitHub repository. I cannot seem to find anything of importance that can remove the bar.

I am aware that I can fix it with:

```
html, body {
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But I'd like to know what is actually causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scollbar disappears when i remove `margin-right: -15px` and `margin-left: -15px` from the `.row` CSS class.

Which actually makes sense because negative margin values strech the content. And if the content already has 100% width you get a horizontal scrollbar.

`div` elements are block elements that allways take 100% space (within their parents).

Comment: added '.row {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;} instead of my solution! Worked perfectly!